# What is the PerfLogs folder for?

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-file

I have tried to find, what the `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\PerfLogs` directory is used for. I could only find answers, each differing and none of them have citations.

Since answers, what give file examples on what files are there are in sub-directories, I suspect that there are more undocumented uses for the folder.

I'm looking for an all-inclusive answer on what files may end up in the folder by the Windows 10 system.

Answers with no citation:
[[1]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-noticed-a-folder-called-perflogs-what-is-it-for/75a4a34a-ebed-421f-96af-1ef71904b1df)
[[2]](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-PerfLogs-folder-in-Windows-10) 
[[3]](https://mymce.wordpress.com/2017/12/02/how-to-relocate-perflogs-folder-in-windows-10/)
[[4]](https://www.easytweaks.com/safe-delete-perflogs-folder-what-is/)
[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_structure)

Answer (score 3):

Performance Logs

PerfLogs (Performance Logs) is a Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 system 
generated folder, that stores a log file of system issues and 
other performance-related reports.

See This And Others using "PerfLogs" in a search at Microsoft.com

> When you are prompted to specify the location to save the performance
>   data, you can accept the default location
>   (**`%systemdrive%\PerfLogs\Admin\<data_collector_set>`**, and then click
>   Next.

Source: [Configure Performance Monitoring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/configure-performance-monitoring)

Comment: I listed the page in my original question. It just says 'it is like that' without any citation.

Comment: I would edit your answer to that. Though the citation is a partial: It is `PerfLogs\Admin`, not `PerfLogs`.

Comment: @vssher - I have properly cited and quote your reference link.  You really should do that yourself in the future.

Comment: @Ramhound, I will try my best at that, thanks, and I appreciate that you edited it. I am trying to learn how to format in this markdown language. I am only used to HTML for now. I know that's no excuse.